# How to press a button on asp.net web site using python+mechanize

Tags: asp.net, python, mechanize

There is a web site I need to scrape. I can fill in the necessary data. The problem is that I don't understand how to press the button to get the page with results.

The button has the following code:

```
<input type="button" value="Search!" onclick="SearchSmth();" id="btSearch">
```

So because the type is not 'submit' attempts to use Browser.submit() fail. I tried using something like this:

```
resp = b.click(type="button", id="btSearch")
```

but it also failed:

```
ClientForm.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching type 'button', kind 'clickable', id 'btSearch'
```

What should I do to get this button pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used [zope.testbrowser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=display&name=zope.testbrowser)? This is wrapper over mechanize module of python. You can use getControl `browser.getControl(name='text-value')` method of zope.testbrowser. You can see more examples [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=display&name=zope.testbrowser)